# Start new intent then open a specific fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-intent

I want to start an intent then automatically selecting a fragment after clicking a button.

This is the function of my button.

`startActivity(new Intent(AlertNotif.this, HomeActivity.class));`

In my HomeActivity.class, it has a BottomNav for different fragments.

```
   bottom_nav.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {

            BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView = (BottomNavigationView)findViewById(R.id.bottom_nav);
            BottomNavigationViewHelper.removeShiftMode(bottomNavigationView);

            switch (item.getItemId()){

                case R.id.nav_map:
                    setFragment(mapFragment);
                    return true;
                case R.id.nav_cctv:
                    setFragment(cctvFragment);
                    return true;
```

My default fragment for the HomeActivity is the mapFragment, i want to set it to cctvFragment after clicking the button, instead of the default fragment. I also tried changing the HomeActivity.class to CctvFragment.class, but it is still opening to default.

Answer (score 0):

On the onCreate of the activity you are calling HomeActivity use:

```
navigation.selectedItemId = R.id.your_id
```

Where navigation is your layout in the xml for the bottomNavigationView and your id is the id of your navigation item!

All it does is call your onNavigationItemSelectListener when the activity is created. 
Remember to set the onNavigationItemSelectListener before you use this code

This code is in Kotlin, I hope is not a problem

Comment: Will this work in Java, or is there a Java equivalent?

Comment: @Enzo bottomNavigationView.setSelectedItemId(R.id.item_id); for Java, usually android studio auto-converts Kotlin to Java and vice versa